# Object reference not set to an instance of an object on mySQL Installer while configuring mySQL Server 8.0.25

Tags: mysql, windows, server, configuration

I recently deleted mySQL and now when i am trying to reinstall it is giving me an error while configuring the mySQL Server
i have tried deleting everything from program file and registry also still no success
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHsAz.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.
When you install with the Installer 1.4, it won't work.

You should be good if you use V.1.6 of the installer.
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be resolved by deleting some hidden files from the C drive which consists of MYSQL files such as configuration files,etc.
You can follow these steps to resolve the issue:

1. Go to your C Drive.
2. Try to locate the option: "View"or near to View,"Hidden Files".
3. Enable those hidden files so that you can see them and now you will be able to see some folders such as of Users, from there choose your user and you might find there MySQL folder, delete this one and search for MySQL folder either in AppData or in some folder named as "Local" or "LocalLow".
4. Try to delete every folder with this name:"MySQL"
5. Now, delete existing mysql installations such as workbench, servers, routers, shell,etc.
6. Now, download the new installer and run that installer, you wont face this issue of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Answer (score 0):

Go to your C Drive.
Try to locate the option: "View"or near to View,"Hidden Files".
Enable those hidden files so that you can see them and now you will be able to see some folders such as of Users, from there choose your user and you might find there MySQL folder, delete this one and search for MySQL folder either in AppData or in some folder named as "Local" or "LocalLow".
Try to delete every folder with this name:"MySQL"
Now, delete existing mysql installations such as workbench, servers, routers, shell,etc.
Now, download the new installer and run that installer, you wont face this issue of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

By using this i can able to get rid from the error